# Django Filter Choice Field displays correct values but wont filter

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-filter

I'm using the Django filter app: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter

I'm making a web-comic app and what I'm trying to accomplish is a drop-down filter field that displays the distinct values for that field. In this case, the ***series*** field.

After reading their docs. And stack overflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455415/using-django-filter-with-choices-field-need-any-option) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932492/dynamic-filter-choice-field-in-django) . I can make the filter form display the correct drop down values. But when I attempt to filter by them, my result queryset returns no values!

There must be something in the docs I'm not understanding. Here's my *hopefully* relevant code.

### models.py

```
class ComicPanel(models.Model):
    #... Other fields

    series = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False, default = getMainSeriesName)

    # Other Filter Fields
    chapter = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    episode = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['series','chapter', 'episode'])
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):  
        super(ComicPanel, self).save()
```

### filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import ComicPanel

# Grab Distinct values for series
def getUniqueSeries():
    series_dicts = ComicPanel.objects.all().values_list('series').distinct()
    series_list = []
    i = 0
    for item in series_dicts:
            series_list.append((i,item[0]))
            i = i+1
    return series_list

class ComicPanelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    series = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices = getUniqueSeries())

    class Meta:
        model = ComicPanel
        fields = ['chapter', 'episode']
```

### views.py

```
def view_archive(request):
    comic_list = ComicPanel.objects.all()
    comic_filter = ComicPanelFilter(request.GET, queryset=comic_list)
    paginator = Paginator(comic_filter.qs, 8)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        comics = paginator.page(page)
    except (PageNotAnInteger, TypeError):
        comics = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        comics = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'comics/comic_archive.html', context = {'filter': comic_filter, 'comics': comics})
```

### template.html

```
...

<form class="form" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="my_classes">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Filter Comics: </th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
          <tbody>
                {% for field in filter.form %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"> {{ field.name }}</th>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}                          
          </tbody>
      </table>              
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Filter</button>       
</form> 

       ...

{% if comics %}
    {% for comic in comics %}                                   
            ...
    {% endfor %}

<!-- if no comics -->
{% else %}
        <p class = "my_class"> Looks like you don't have any comics! Upload some? </p>
{% endif %}
```

### Results:

My filter form displays the correct, distinct ***series*** for the drop down items. But When I *filter* by any value, the queryset returns no comics

I've also tried using the *ModelChoiceFilter* in my filters class with a similar result (but the values show up in a Tuple format):

```
series=django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=ComicPanel.objects.all().values_list('series').distinct())
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your `ComicPanel` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem made an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was pretty silly actually,

If we look at the [Django docs for field.choices:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices)

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.

So this method:

```
# Grab Distinct values for series
def getUniqueSeries():
     series_dicts = ComicPanel.objects.all().values_list('series').distinct()
     series_list = []
     i = 0
     for item in series_dicts:
            series_list.append((i,item[0]))
            i = i+1
     return series_list
```

returns a list that looks like: [(0,'series1'), (1, 'series2'), ...]

For my model, the first value of the tuple needs to be the series name. 
So the list should look like: 
[('series1','series1'), ('series2', 'series2'), ...]

So the simple fix is to change this line:

```
series_list.append((i,item[0]))
```

to this:

```
series_list.append((item[0],item[0]))
```